# What argument must change in order for refetching to occur with 'refetchOnMountOrArgChange'?

Tags: redux, react-redux, arguments, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

To quote [the official Redux Toolkit Query documentation for 'refetchOnMountOrArgChange' here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/cache-behavior#encouraging-re-fetching-with-refetchonmountorargchange):

> I.e., when the component calling the hook mounts, or the argument
> changes, it will always refetch, regardless of whether cached data for
> the endpoint + arg combination already exists.

Does ***'argument'*** refer to the attributes/'props' of the new component, or the argument passed to the hook?

Isn't it obvious that if the argument to the query hook changes, fetching must occur since there has been no associated cache entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the argument of the hook. The hook would not have a way to know that the component props changed if you think about it ;)

Imagine you go from `usePage(1)` to `usePage(2)` and then back to `usePage(1)` - all in the same component. At that point the cache entry for page 1 could still be in the cache - and with `refetchOnMountOrArgChange` you can decide at which point the cache entry is considered "too old" and a refetch would be necessary.